# How to add multiple HttpMessageHandler to HttpClient without HttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have a console application that uses [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)) to make web requests.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
```

I'm trying to add multiple [HttpMessageHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler(v=vs.118).aspx) to it (custom implementations of [DelegatingHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler(v=vs.118).aspx), really) but the [constructor for HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193664(v=vs.118).aspx) only takes a single [HttpMessageHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler(v=vs.118).aspx).

```
class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler { //... }
class ResponseContentProcessingHandler : DelegatingHandler { //... }
```

this is ok...

```
var client = new HttpClient(new LoggingHandler()); // OK
```

but this doesn't compile:

```
var client = new HttpClient(
                new LoggingHandler(), 
                new ResponseContentProcessingHandler()); // Sadness
```

Because I'm targeting .NET 4.0, I cannot use [HttpClientFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientfactory(v=vs.118).aspx), which is how the solution to this problem is commonly explained:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(
                       new LoggingHandler(),
                       new ResponseContentProcessingHandler());
```

Because I'm just in a console application, rather than in an ASP.NET application, I can't do this either:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                   .MessageHandlers
                   .Add(new LoggingHandler()
                   .Add(new ResponseContentProcessingHandler());
```

I've looked at the [source for HttpClientFactory](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpClientFactory.cs) and there doesn't seem to be anything in there that wouldn't compile in .NET 4.0, but short of rolling my own factory ("inspired" by Microsoft's source code), is there a way to manually add many HTTP message handlers to the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx))?

Comment: It does not matter if you are using console or asp.net, Web API meant to be using http protocol anyway.

Comment: @Zara_me are you saying that you can get to `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers` in a console application? Because I'm saying I can't. What does the HTTP protocol have to do with it?

Comment: if you can not use  HttpClientFactory in console , isn't better to use a minimal web page hosting and sending Httpconfiguration object and for testing use Fiddler2.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you can just do something like this:

```
var loggingHandler = new LoggingHandler();
var responseContentProcessingHandler =  new ResponseContentProcessingHandler();
loggingHandler.InnerHandler = responseContentProcessingHandler;
var client = new HttpClient(loggingHandler);
```

So that you don't need to create a CustomHandler just for the chaining purpose.
That's really the purpose of DelegatingHandler.

Answer (score 35):

DelegatingHandler has a [protected constructor that takes a handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193588(v=vs.118).aspx) for the inner handler. If you have control over all your custom handlers, I would think you can add a public constructor that calls the protected constructor, like:

```
public class CustomHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public CustomHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler)
    {
    }
}
```

and chain them thus:

```
var client = new HttpClient(
    new CustomHandler(
        new OtherCustomerHandler(
            new HttpClientHandler()
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: +1 for actually showing how to chain multiple handlers, especially with `HttpClientHandler` appearing at the innermost level so it can preserve the behaviour you get from `HttpClient` when you use its parameterless constructor. The docs mention chaining but I couldn't see an example anywhere!

Answer (score 5):

In case of using [AddHttpClient extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) you can use `IHttpClientBuilder` to configure all chain of `DelegateHandler`-s.

```
ServiceCollection
    .AddHttpClient("MyClient")
    .ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.AdditionalHandlers.Add(builder.Services.GetRequiredService<YourFirstHandler>());
        builder.PrimaryHandler = builder.Services.GetRequiredService<YourLastHandler>();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To Achieve with Console application on .Net 4.0 platform,best possible solution is to pass httpConfiguration to your webapi library or if you dont hold WebAPI code just write this code in global.ascx file of webhost asp.net application

```
     protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        WebAPIConfig.Configure(config);


    }

   //Code that will configure all message handlers in webapi    
          public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration configure)
   {


        configure.MessageHandlers.Add(new xyzhandler());
       configure.MessageHandlers.Add(new ABCHandler());

   }
```

In your Console Application,place uri of your webhost hosting webapi

```
   private const string APiUri="http://localhost/api/get"
   using(HttpClient cleint=new HttpClient()){
     var response await cleint.GetAsync(ApiUri);
    ....
               }
```

Comment: the implementation of "calling/registering" the multiple handlers is what's eluding me - can you edit this answer to include a code snippet explaining what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

For .NET C#, in case someone who is also looking to do something similar, I was able to archive it with a static builder/factory:

```
namespace SomeNamespace {
  public class ConcreteDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler {}

  public class DelegateHandlerFactory
  {
    public static DelegatingHandler Build(dynamic[] handlers)
    {
      DelegatingHandler wrapper = new ConcreteDelegatingHandler();
      DelegatingHandler current = wrapper;
      HttpMessageHandler last = handlers.Last();

      foreach (dynamic handler in handlers)
      {
        if (handler == last)
          current.InnerHandler = handler;
        else if (current is DelegatingHandler)
        {
          current.InnerHandler = handler;
          current = handler;
        }
        else throw new InvalidOperationException("Intermediate handlers must be of type DelegatingHandler");
      }  
      return wrapper;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
HttpMessageHandler[] handlers = {
  myDelegatingHandler1,
  myDelegatingHandler2,
  ...
  myDelegatingHandlerN
};

var handler = DelegateHandlerFactory.Build(handlers);
HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(handler, true);
```